# Deploying Next.js Project to Heroku Failure

Tags: reactjs, heroku, next.js

I'm trying to Deploy my next.js project on heroku but on the app run, it fails and this is the log of the failure.

```
2019-11-17T18:23:33.067077+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pens-nextjs.herokuapp.com request_id=f01abc4b-bf9b-4f2e-8b8e-06184580bfc8 fwd="41.232.85.202" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-11-17T18:23:37.203987+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pens-nextjs.herokuapp.com request_id=f4f94391-c79c-4503-9751-fe8a6c5461d3 fwd="41.232.85.202" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-11-17T18:23:38.045712+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pens-nextjs.herokuapp.com request_id=98cc2b80-5631-4af1-9889-26abecca6aec fwd="41.232.85.202" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: What else do your application logs say?

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same issue.
I added favicon.ico in public folder of my NextJs App. Also, add following lines in your package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start -p $PORT",
  "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build",
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
```

Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 1):

Next.js binds to port 3000 by default, while Heroku expects your server process to bind to the port supplied in the `PORT` environment variable. You can make the Next.js server to bind to this port by modifying `package.json` to have `"start": "next start -p $PORT"`.